# Lifting a group homomorphism via a covering map

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, covering-spaces

Let $\tilde{G},G,H$ be topological groups with $H$ connected, $f:H\to G$  a continuous group homomorphism, and $p:\tilde{G}\to G$ be a covering map that is also a group homomorphism. Suppose $\tilde{f}:H\to \tilde{G}$ is a continuous lift of $f$ with $\tilde{f}(e)=e$. (Note that since $H$ is connected, such a lift $\tilde{f}$ is unique if it exists.) Then is it true that $\tilde{f}$ is necessarily a group homomorphism? At least we have $p\tilde{f}(xy)=f(xy)=f(x)f(y)=p\tilde{f}(x) p\tilde{f}(y)=p(\tilde{f}(x)\tilde{f}(y))$, so $\tilde{f}(xy)$ and $\tilde{f}(x)\tilde{f}(y)$ are contained in the same fiber of $p$, but I can't see why these two must be equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is you can use the uniqueness of lifts to compare $\tilde{f}(xy)$ and $\tilde{f}(x)\tilde{f}(y)$.  Let $g(y)=\tilde{f}(xy)$ and $h(y)=\tilde{f}(x)\tilde{f}(y)$.  Then $g$ and $h$ are both lifts of $pg=ph:H\to G$ with $g(e)=h(e)=\tilde{f}(x)$.  Therefore, they are equal.